# Filter & iterating through stdclass object array with Bigcommerce API

Tags: php, api, curl, bigcommerce

I'm trying to use Big commerce API and filter the json response to whatever parameters I need. Ideally I'd like to filter the customers that have an addres in Sydney, Australia and a shipping status of "awaiting pickup". Here's a beginning I've written:

```
 <?php

    //Bigcommerce API credentials
    $username = 'xxxxxx'; 
    $api = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

    //Curl requests
    // Assign filters to variables
    $city_name = 'Sydney';
    $country_name = 'Australia';
    $items_shipped = 0;


    $customer_url = "https://store-xxxxxx.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/customers.json";

    // intiate curl request
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $customer_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $api);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");

    // execute curl requests
    $curlData = curl_exec($curl);

    // Parse requests in Json Format
    $product_rec  = json_decode($curlData);

    // returns a specific variable of StdClass Object, here the first name of obj[1]
     echo $product_rec[0]->first_name;

     // !!Here I'd like to implement an iteration othe reach std class objects and filter!!

    // print the requests in Json format on screen
     echo '<pre>';
     print_r($product_rec);

    // Close curl connexions
    curl_close($curl);

?>
```

For now I'm getting this answer:

```
Hyacinthe
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [company] => 
            [first_name] => Hyacinthe
            [last_name] => Hamon
            [email] => yayahappy@yahoo.com
            [phone] => 0671089566
            [date_created] => Fri, 26 Feb 2016 05:19:27 +0000
            [date_modified] => Fri, 26 Feb 2016 05:19:27 +0000
            [store_credit] => 0.0000
            [registration_ip_address] => 138.25.2.134
            [customer_group_id] => 0
            [notes] => 
            [tax_exempt_category] => 
            [reset_pass_on_login] => 
            [addresses] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [url] => https://store-xxxxxx.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/customers/1/addresses.json
                    [resource] => /customers/1/addresses
                )

            [form_fields] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [company] => Zip
            [first_name] => John
            [last_name] => Lennon
            [email] => john@beattles.com
            [phone] => 
            [date_created] => Sat, 27 Feb 2016 01:31:19 +0000
            [date_modified] => Sat, 27 Feb 2016 01:31:19 +0000
            [store_credit] => 0.0000
            [registration_ip_address] => 114.75.66.199
            [customer_group_id] => 0
            [notes] => 
            [tax_exempt_category] => 
            [reset_pass_on_login] => 
            [addresses] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [url] => https://store-xxxxxx.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/customers/2/addresses.json
                    [resource] => /customers/2/addresses
                )

            [form_fields] => 
        )

)
```

I'd like to filter now the results with the variables. I think I need to do a foreach loop but I'm not sure how to do it. Can anyone help please?

Comment: I would really appreciate if someone could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd actually start with the orders object instead. This would provide both the billing and shipping address as well as the order status ID. The order status ID could be filtered and then you can use the remaining results to filter for Sydney, Australia. 
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/orders

```
    /api/v2/orders?status_id={value}
```

I'm not sure why you are trying to go through the customers resource first. If you are concerned about checking for an existing customer account, you can look for a customer ID that has a value other than 0.

Comment: Thanks alice, I should have filtered by order status ID from the start )